# Extract contour vertices from a dataframe

Tags: r, contour

Hi guys and thanks in advance for your help.

I have a three-column dataframe, two with coordinates for my data (x and y) and a value of brain activity (z). Out of 7505 rows there are many coordinates with null data that I need to exclude for my statistical analysis.

I'm using the package ImageSCC (https://rdrr.io/github/funstatpackages/ImageSCC/man/) so I need to extract the boundaries or contour of my data, meaning that I need a two-column list of the coordinates that separate brain activity data from null data. This is an example provided by the package:

```
    $Brain.V1
              V1         V2
 [1,] 0.07781920 0.33867403
 [2,] 0.07781920 0.56408840
 [3,] 0.07781920 0.65469613
 [4,] 0.07968313 0.43812155
 [5,] 0.10950606 0.50000000
 [6,] 0.11323392 0.25690608
 [7,] 0.12068966 0.73425414
 [8,] 0.16728798 0.18176796
 [9,] 0.19897484 0.83812155
[10,] 0.23625349 0.10441989
[11,] 0.26663278 0.63322031
[12,] 0.28808616 0.46804766
[13,] 0.28939153 0.30397021
[14,] 0.30335508 0.91325967
[15,] 0.31081081 0.04033149
[16,] 0.37862235 0.75747676
[17,] 0.42193552 0.19377116
[18,] 0.42823858 0.02044199
[19,] 0.43196645 0.94419890
[20,] 0.44787179 0.57753089
[21,] 0.45363822 0.38319933
[22,] 0.54193849 0.02554144
[23,] 0.54231688 0.73945984
[24,] 0.55125815 0.92756906
[25,] 0.58275116 0.25043703
[26,] 0.59755088 0.47843551
[27,] 0.63513514 0.89662983
[28,] 0.64072693 0.07616022
[29,] 0.66888720 0.64103671
[30,] 0.71390307 0.35218048
[31,] 0.72087605 0.84138122
[32,] 0.75069897 0.15050829
[33,] 0.78631797 0.50829246
[34,] 0.79543336 0.77508287
[35,] 0.84016775 0.26132597
[36,] 0.85507922 0.69552486
[37,] 0.92845294 0.39287293
[38,] 0.92845294 0.60502762
```

I have tried with the package 'contoureR' but every time I run my code Rstudio crashes and reboots session. This is a sample of my code:

```
#install.packages("contoureR")
library(contoureR)

x = 1:ncol(df)
y = 1:nrow(df)
z = expand.grid(x=x,y=y)

z$z = apply(z,1,function(xx){df[xx[1],xx[2]]})
z$z[is.nan(z$z)] <- 0 


cl = getContourLines(z)
```

Does anyone have other idea about how could I extract the boundaries of my data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the moment, let's forget contoureR, and stick with your data, Edit and dput(your_data[some_#:some#]), that gives (x,y,z) including null for excluding. Then boundaries?

Comment: Output looks like the following:

dput(sample_30[760:800,], file = "sample30", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", "niceNames", "showAttributes"))

`structure(list(x = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), y = 20:40, pet = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.653315663337708, 0.78192275762558, 0.902566969394684, 
1.0171445608139, 1.10856020450592, 1.16762030124664, 1.20366621017456, 
1.23127448558807, 1.2537043094635, 1.26001739501953, 1.25276708602905, 
1.24699950218201, 1.24693524837494)), row.names = 218425:218445, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: So I have two kinds of brain activity levels: either it is positive (there is brain tissue in that coordinate) or a null value (air, no brain tissue in that coordinate). In order to minimize errors I need to exclude all the air from my analysis.

Comment: How much RAM do you have and Win, OSx or Linux? When Rstudio gives up, panics, crashes, it is usually memory. We might need to figure out a way to chunk up the data, process parts, then stitch it back together.

Comment: Yeah! That's it. I rounded my values to just two decimals and used just a subset of 500 rows and it worked. The result is not useful but that's a start.

My session and laptop info:

Rsesion 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

RAM: 16Gb (15'8Gb usable)

Now the question is how to reduce the memory needings...

Comment: For some reason I can work with all my rows but for the last one. I mean, my data has 7505 rows and this works:

'df = getContourLines(dat[1:7504,],levels=c(0))'

But this causes R to abort session:

'df = getContourLines(dat[1:7505,],levels=c(0))'

Comment: I'm getting timed out continually at github trying to get ImageSCC. Is your data in either ImageSCC or contoureR, or your own? And how can I get? And I saw a good overview post on chunking (and there are several pkgs) that I'll try to track down again.

Comment: Oh, you're last comment is interesting. It might just be something like voodoo, but in the grand scheme, how important is that last line?

Comment: Well, I could work something out with that "mutillated" contour but once I got here I'd like to know why 7504 rows is OK and 7505 is not OK.

I added the following line to the script, nothing changed. 'memory.size(max = TRUE)' 

So no memory problem.

Comment: It is an index problem, but why the crash? So we need something other than rstudio to say how many rows as a kind of check on the data source, or use readlines() and take 7504, then 7505. Have to convert text back to numeric. Your memory.size also means you probably don't have to truncate your precision.

Comment: I did some research on index problems and realised that my rows started at 2 and ended at 7505. I included this to my script: 'rownames(df) <- NULL' to correct that but the problem persists.

I also realised that contour works both for 'dat[1:7504,]' and for 'dat[2:7505,]'

Comment: How is the data first read in from file, headers = TRUE, skip = 1 (which should get rid of the empty row 1)?

Comment: read.csv2("dat",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=";", dec = ",")

Comment: so `read.csv2("dat",header=T,skip=1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=";", dec = ",")` should end the index part of the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't I loose one of my rows and thus part of my data?

Comment: Well, you said rows started at 2, which suggests 1 is blank (no data, no nothing) and should be skipped. When I start playing with a new file type I usually open it is a decent text editor to get a sense of how it is organized.

Comment: Oh my god, lost internet for an hour. Not a happy condition when `sheltering in place`.

Comment: I meant that the row name for first row is '2'. And so on, meaning also that the 7505º value's name is 7506. I do obtained contours for 7504 values with one missing, as someone pointed out previously this is not perfect but still I can manage to work with that if I can't find a definitive solution.

Comment: can you send me sample_30? I've gone about as far as I can without data.